# I'm building an expo application. app is running.but whenever i use npx expo run:android it crashes with these errors. I tried many things but in vain

Tags: expo, location, maps

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Doctor'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5.1' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1.
> Required by:
> project : > project :react-native-gradle-plugin
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5.1' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s

> Here are my app.json and package.json files

app.json

```
{
"expo": {
    "name": "Doctor",
    "slug": "Doctor",
    "version": "1.0.4",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "plugins": [["expo-location"]],
    "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/splash.png",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
        "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
        "adaptiveIcon": {
            "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "permissions": [
            "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
            "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION",
            "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        ],
        "package": "com.anonymous.Doctor",
        "versionCode": 3,
        "config": {
            "googleMaps": {
                "apiKey": "API_KEY"
            }
        }
    },
    "web": {
        "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
        "eas": {
            "projectId": "b68344f5-0eb0-42f7-a1a0-8e7805a97643"
        }
    }
}
```

}

package.json

```
{
"name": "doctor",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
},
"private": true
```

}

Answer (score 2):

the same thing happened to me.

Install sdk 17 and point JAVA_HOME in the environment variables
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.

And u solve the problem.

Comment: It maybe a problem but main problem was dependencies in my package.json i was not following proper guide and did not install react-native-screens and safe-area-context with react-navigation. Which is necessary. It was problem for me.